# Use Firebase Authentication signInAnonymously from Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use Firebase Auth signInAnonymously from Firebase Cloud Functions with node.js to log in users in my firebase app and control their interaction in my web app, but I have not been able to achieve it, typescript precompilation shows me this **error**:

```
Property 'signInAnonimously' does not exist on type 'Auth'
```

I'm importing firebase auth like the following:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
const auth = admin.auth()
```

And then in my function I'm using it like this:

```
auth.signInAnonimously().catch(function (error) {return {success: false}})
```

[Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) is the reference of the previous code from Firebase docs.

I know two things:

1- Authentication could be used from Cloud Functions because I'm creating users in the same way and it works (with createUser function).

2- The easiest way to do it is in front-end code with Javascript, which works correctly, but I dont want this kind of code be visible on the clients side (Browser console), and I have a firebase function to pre-process the requests in my app.

Is there any way to make it work from functions?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Introduction to the Admin Auth API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/) indicates the use cases for auth with the admin (node) SDK. The [admin.auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth) namespace does not support the [signInAnonymously()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInAnonymously) client-side method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response

Comment: Hi there! If the answer solved you questions, please accept it